# Trying to add a second parent node to a child node using d3 tree chart library

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to create a `D3 Tree`, and able to get the task done to some extent, but in my situation, there can be more than 1 parent node to a single node.

But as I've learned, I still need to start off with one root node to build the tree, and I did that and was able to build the tree, and now want to add a second node to a tree node.

```js
var data = [{
  "children": [{
    "children": [{
      "children": [{
        "children": [

        ],
        "name": "Hierarchy Child 5",
        "parent": "Hierarchy Sibling",
        "relation": "Parent Of",
        "rid": "a059000000VBecUAAT"
      }],
      "name": "Hierarchy Sibling",
      "parent": "Hierarchy Parent",
      "relation": "Parent Of",
      "rid": "a059000000VBKeYAAX"
    }, {
      "children": [{
        "children": [

        ],
        "name": "Hierarchy Child 1",
        "parent": "ACME",
        "relation": "Parent Of",
        "rid": "a059000000VBKf7AAH"
      }, {
        "children": [

        ],
        "name": "Hierarchy Child 2",
        "parent": "ACME",
        "relation": "Parent Of",
        "rid": "a059000000VBKfCAAX"
      }, {
        "children": [

        ],
        "name": "Hierarchy Child 3",
        "parent": "ACME",
        "relation": "Parent Of",
        "rid": "a059000000VBKfHAAX"
      }, {
        "children": [

        ],
        "name": "Hierarchy Child 4",
        "parent": "ACME",
        "relation": "Parent Of",
        "rid": "a059000000VBKfMAAX"
      }],
      "name": "ACME",
      "parent": "Hierarchy Parent",
      "relation": "Parent Of",
      "rid": "a059000000VBKeJAAX"
    }],
    "name": "Hierarchy Parent",
    "parent": "This is Test Second Parent Node",
    "relation": "Parent Of",
    "rid": "a059000000VBKeOAAX"
  }, {
    "children": [

    ],
    "name": "Hierarchy Uncle",
    "parent": "Hierarchy Grandparent",
    "relation": "Parent Of",
    "rid": "a059000000VBKedAAH"
  }, {
    "children": [

    ],
    "name": "Hierarchy Great Uncle",
    "parent": "Hierarchy Grandparent",
    "relation": "Parent Of",
    "rid": "a059000000VBKenAAH"
  }],
  "name": "Hierarchy Grandparent",
  "parent": "null",
  "relation": "Parent Of",
  "rid": "a059000000VBKeTAAX"
}];

// *********** Convert flat data into a nice tree ***************
// create a name: node map
var dataMap = data.reduce(function(map, node) {
  map[node.name] = node;
  return map;
}, {});

// create the tree array
var treeData = [];
data.forEach(function(node) {
  // add to parent
  var parent = dataMap[node.parent];
  if (parent) {
    // create child array if it doesn't exist
    (parent.children || (parent.children = []))
    // add node to child array
    .push(node);
  } else {
    // parent is null or missing
    treeData.push(node);
  }
});

// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
  },
  width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.y, d.x];
  });

var svg = d3.select("div#chart-container").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = treeData[0];

update(root);

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 180;
  });

  // Declare the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter the nodes.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", "#fff");

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Declare the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });

  // Enter the links.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", diagonal);

}
```

```css
.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart-container">

</div>
```

As  we can see, the code runs fine and tree is generating but my JSON data array has a second parent on node with `name` as `Hierarchy Parent` has a `parent` specified as `This is Test Second Parent Node` but this node does not appear on tree.

This Image is what I'm trying to generate as output:
[image: Expected desired output]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example

http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/6afc2ecb05b191359862

If that doesn't help, you might want to take a look at the force directed graph

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

Also take a look at [cytoscape](http://js.cytoscape.org/), very similar to d3 but it deals with networks (graph data structure) as well as trees http://js.cytoscape.org/demos/aedff159b0df05ccfaa5/

Comment: This multi parent tree looks like what I need here, but I'm not able to understand the `couplingParent1` and `couplingChild1` code, which seems to be the thing I need to do in my code to make multi parent relationship work :-(

Comment: Looks from the source like there is some custom code to draw the parent (see bottom of file) http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/raw/6afc2ecb05b191359862/dndTree.js